# How to stop my code from printing "Ascending" more than once?

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, if-statement

My code is:

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in your order(ex.5 7 4 6 8 3 9 2 0 1 - SPACES REQUIRED): ");
    String input=sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<input.length(); i++) {
    String[] b=input.split(" ");
    if(Integer.valueOf(b[i]) < Integer.valueOf(b[i+1])) { 
        System.out.println("Acsending"); 
    }
    else { // When condition is false 
            System.out.println("Mixed"); 
        }
    }
```

But when my input is`1 2 3 4 5 6`, the output is:

`Ascending
Ascending
Ascending
Ascending
Ascending`

And when my input is `1 4 2 5 2`, the output is, 

`Ascending
Mixed
Ascending
Mixed`

How do I make the code print only if the input is mixed or ascending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the guy who answer before me (Elliott Frisch) is PRO 
I have no Idea what this line does and what those :: Does

```
Arrays.stream(input.split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```

I'm a beginner myself, this is how i did it

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    Scanner sc =new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type in your order(ex.5 7 4 6 8 3 9 2 0 1 - SPACES REQUIRED): ");
    String input=sc.nextLine();
    String[] b=input.split(" "); 

    sc.close(); //Always Close Scanner after user  :)
    boolean isMixed = false; // Flag

    for(int i=0; i < input.length()/2; i++) //input.length() is equal to number + Spaces we don't want spaces
    {
        //Integer.parseInt(b[i]) converting string to Integer
        if(Integer.parseInt(b[i]) < Integer.parseInt(b[i+1]))
        {
            isMixed = false; 
        } 
        else 
        {
            isMixed = true;
        }

    }

    if(isMixed)
    {
         System.out.println("Mixed"); 
    } else
    {
        System.out.println("Ascending"); 
    }

}
```